# Unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, bitbucket

I have containers for multiple Atlassian products; `JIRA`, `Bitbucket` and `Confluence`. When I'm trying to access the running containers I'm usually using:

```
docker exec -it -u root ${DOCKER_CONTAINER} bash
```

With this command I'm able to access as usual, but after running a script to extract and compress log files, I can't access that one container anymore.

### Excerpt from the 'clean up script'

This is the first point of failure, and the script is running once each week (scheduled by Jenkins).

```
docker cp ${CLEAN_UP_SCRIPT} ${DOCKER_CONTAINER}:/tmp/${CLEAN_UP_SCRIPT}
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  docker exec -it -u root ${DOCKER_CONTAINER} bash -c "cd ${LOG_DIR} && /tmp/compressOldLogs.sh ${ARCHIVE_FILE}"
fi
```

When the script executes these two lines towards the Bitbucket container the result is:

```
unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file
```

It's failing on the 'docker cp'-command, but only towards the Bitbucket container. After the script has ran, the container is unaccessible with both the 'bitbucket' (defined in Dockerfile) and 'root' users.

I was able to copy `/etc/passwd` out of the container, and it contains all of the users as expected. When trying to access by uid, I get the following error:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: process_linux.go:75: starting setns process caused "fork/exec /proc/self/exe: no such file or directory"
```

### Dockerfile for Bitbucket image:

```
FROM                        java:openjdk-8-jre

ENV BITBUCKET_HOME          /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket
ENV BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR   /opt/atlassian/bitbucket
ENV BITBUCKET_VERSION       4.12.0
ENV DOWNLOAD_URL            https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/stash/downloads/atlassian-bitbucket-${BITBUCKET_VERSION}.tar.gz

ARG user=bitbucket
ARG group=bitbucket
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000

RUN mkdir -p $(dirname $BITBUCKET_HOME) \
    && groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
    && useradd -d "$BITBUCKET_HOME" -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m -s /bin/bash ${user}

RUN mkdir -p                                ${BITBUCKET_HOME} \
    && mkdir -p                             ${BITBUCKET_HOME}/shared \
    && chmod -R 700                         ${BITBUCKET_HOME} \
    && chown -R ${user}:${group}            ${BITBUCKET_HOME} \
    && mkdir -p                             ${BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR}/conf/Catalina \
    && curl -L --silent                     ${DOWNLOAD_URL} | tar -xz --strip=1 -C "$BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR" \
    && chmod -R 700                         ${BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR}/ \
    && chown -R ${user}:${group}            ${BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR}/

${BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR}/bin/setenv.sh

USER        ${user}:${group}

EXPOSE      7990
EXPOSE      7999

WORKDIR     $BITBUCKET_INSTALL_DIR
CMD         ["bin/start-bitbucket.sh", "-fg"]
```

### Additional info:

- Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
- docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7
- All containers are running at all times, even Bitbucket works as usual after the issue occurres
- The issue disappears after a restart of the container

Comment: I've encountered this and usually stop/start of container helps, but it's annoying

Comment: Problem also referenced on Docker forum : https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-find-user-root-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file/26545

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is caused by a **docker engine bug** but which is **tracked privately**, Docker is asking users to restart the engine!

It seems that the bug is likely to be older than two years!

https://success.docker.com/article/ucp-health-checks-fail-unable-to-find-user-nobody-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file-observed

https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-find-user-root-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file/26545/7

... what can I say, someone is doing his best to get more funding.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this command to access to the container with root user:

> docker exec -u 0 -i -t {container_name_or_hash} /bin/bash

try debug with that. i think the script maybe remove or disable root user.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question (first command listed), I've tried that; "_When trying to access by uid, I get the following error:_" 
`rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: process_linux.go:75: starting setns process caused "fork/exec /proc/self/exe: no such file or directory"`

Answer (score 3):

Its a Long standing issue, replicated on my old version 1.10.3 to at least 1.17

As mentioned by @sorin the the [docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-find-user-root-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file/26545) says `Running docker stop and then docker start fixes the problem but is hardly a long-term solution`...

The `docker exec -u 0 -i -t {container_name_or_hash} /bin/bash` solution also in the same forum post mentioned here by @ObranZoltan might work for you, but does not work for many. See my output below

```
$ sudo docker exec -u 0 -it berserk_nobel /bin/bash 
exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: input/output error
```