# Cannot exec into docker container due to application

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker

Yesterday I restarted my docker container for my database. My applications can still connect as normal however:

The following line no-longer works

```
docker exec -i -t database_1 bash
```

Instead it gives me this error:

```
unable to find user postgres: no matching entries in passwd file
```

I don't know why it's not just giving me bash

Comment: This is a duplicate question and is caused by known docker bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726544/99834

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you switched to a different user in the Dockerfile, but never created it. Try this:

```
docker exec -it --user root database_1 /bin/bash
```

Comment: Same issue
`unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file`

Strangly if I use the numeric id it works
`docker exec -it --user 0 database_1 /bin/bash`

Comment: @Jordan Did you manage to screw up the /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow files?

Comment: Never touched either of those files in my life. Is it possible that postgres made some change to it?

Comment: @Jordan Share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of bug in docker.  Apparently `docker stop <container>; docker start <container>` will fix it, and using `docker cp` can cause it to happen.