# Docker: docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user myuser: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: docker

```
[root@mymachine redisc]# docker run -p 6379:6379 --user myuser redisc
docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user myuser: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

but i can become myuser on the host

```
[root@mymachine redisc]# sudo su myuser
[myuser@mymachine redisc]#
```

How would i be able to run as myuser in the container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676835/docker-unable-to-find-user-root-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file)

Comment: Duplicate caused by long standing docker bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726544/99834

Answer (score 35):

According to the documentation you can use the ID of the user / group:

> When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in the container.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

The command could look like this:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 --user 1001 redisc
```

Comment: Great answer. This should have more upvotes. Works perfectly on docker `v 19.03.14`. So, as it turns out, we can pass a userId (UID) that exists on the hosts (but not necessarily present on the container) to the `--user` option of `docker run`.

Comment: what if we are doing this on windows machine?

Answer (score 16):

The host and the container are completely separate. You need to create `myuser` *inside* the redisc container before you try and run stuff as that user.

Comment: i added "RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash myuser" in the Dockerfile and I still get the same error

Comment: oh I had the line "USER myuser" before RUN. I commented out "USER myuser" and it seems to be working

Comment: It's not necessary to create a user on the container. As it turns out, we can pass a userId (UID) that exists on the hosts (but not necessarily present on the container) to the `--user` option of `docker run`. Tested on docker `v 19.03.14`

Answer (score 4):

You can mount read-only the host user info

```
# user user and group IDs:
usr="--user $(id -u myuser):$(id -g myuser)"
mountdirs="-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro"

options="-p 6379:6379"
# I use 
# options="-ti --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash"

image=redisc

docker run ${options} ${usr} ${mountdirs} -w /home/myuser "${image}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly thought a permission denied error was about access to my filesystem. I built a container that has a bash script as the entrypoint, but didn't give myself execution permission before building the image.

`chmod +x entrypoint.sh` and rebuilding the image solved my issue.

Comment: This solved this issue for me when I ran into it, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

> [root@host ~]# docker run --user=toto -ti fedora:26 uname
>
> /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: linux spec user:
>   unable to find user toto: no matching entries in passwd file.
>
> [root@host ~]# docker run --user=`id -u toto` -ti fedora:26 uname
>
> Linux